# Real Analysis: function continuity examples

Tags: real-analysis

> Provide a function for each of the following examples. If not, just state impossible.
>
> a) $f : (0, 4) \to \Bbb R$ is continuous and attains a maximum value of $1$ and a minimum value of $0$.

My function is 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/4x+1/2 &\text{if $x \in (0,2)$} \\
-x+3 &\text{if $x \in [2,3)$} \\
1/2x-3/2 &\text{if $x \in [3,4)$.} \\
\end{cases}$$

> b) $f : [0, 4] \to \Bbb R$ attains a minimum, but fails to attain a maximum.

My function is $f(x)=(x-1)^2$.

> c) $f : [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, but attains neither a maximum nor a minimum.

My function is $f(x)=x\sin(x)$

Could anyone please check them for me?

Comment: have you tried at all? You may try to draw the graphs to have a better understanding

Comment: I did draw graphs for all of them but I just want to make sure they are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer to b) doesn't work  since f has a max of 9 when x = 4. We can take the function
f(x) = x on [0, 4) and f(4) = 1. Clearly the min = 0 and there is no max.

Comment: your domain = [0, 4] is what makes f attain a max value.

Comment: sorry. i missed it

Comment: One "working function" is for example take: f(x) = x for 0<= x <4,and f(x) = 1 when x = 4. This does the job for you.

Comment: Does the following function work

Comment: My function is 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x &\text{if $x \in [0,4)$} \\
1 &\text{if $x = 4$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: this is what I think too...thx

Comment: If domain condition is [0,4) then my original function, f(x) = (x-1)^2 will work right?

Comment: Yes it will or you can make another piecewise function like that.